# Issues Creating Apache Kudu Range Partitioned Table

Tags: partitioning, illegalstateexception, kudu

I am trying to create a simple Kudu table with Hash and Range Partitions.
When I try to use a Decimal(18,0) for the Range partition I get the following error:
***IllegalStateException: null***

```
drop table if exists mydb.xxx;
create table if NOT EXISTS mydb.xxx (
            tx_id                      decimal(18,0)    not null ,
            tdl_id                     decimal(18,0)    not null ,
            dt1                        int ,                  
    PRIMARY KEY(tx_id,tdl_id) )
    PARTITION BY 
        HASH(tx_id,tdl_id) PARTITIONS 22 ,
        RANGE (tx_id )
    (
        partition values < 1000 ,
        partition 1000 <= values
    )
    stored as kudu;
```

This Statement works:

```
drop table if exists mydb.xxx;
create table if NOT EXISTS mydb.xxx (
            tx_id                      bigint         not null ,
            tdl_id                     decimal(18,0)  not null ,
            dt1                        int ,                  
    PRIMARY KEY(tx_id,tdl_id) )
    PARTITION BY 
        HASH(tx_id,tdl_id) PARTITIONS 22 ,
        RANGE (tx_id )
    (
        partition values < 1000 ,
        partition 1000 <= values
    )
    stored as kudu;
```

The only difference is the data type for tx_id
Does anyone know if it is illegal to use decimal datatypes for range partitioning in Kudu?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check kudu tablet server thread then run this change

```
drop table if exists mydb.xxx;
create table if NOT EXISTS mydb.xxx (
            tx_id                      bigint         not null ,
            tdl_id                     decimal(18,0)  not null ,
            dt1                        int ,                  
    PRIMARY KEY(tx_id,tdl_id) )
    PARTITION BY 
        HASH(tx_id,tdl_id) PARTITIONS 22 ,
        RANGE (tx_id )
    (
        partition values < 1000 ,
        partition values = 1000 , 
        partition values >= 1000
    )
    stored as kudu;
```